# If $\,\lim_{x\to 0} \Big(f\big({a\over x}+b\big) - {a\over x}\,f'\big({a\over x}+b\big)\Big)=c,\,$ find $\,\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, derivatives

> Let $f$ be differentiable on $\mathbb R$ . If $\lim_{x\to 0}f\big({a\over x}+b\big)\ne 0$ and $$\lim_{x\to 0} \Big(f\big({a\over x}+b\big) - {a\over x}\,f'\big({a\over x}+b\big)\Big)=c,$$ find $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)$.

I had been using L' Hopital's rule, but after I thought it was wrong.

Comment: Is $a>0$? What about $b$?

Comment: mm... yes. $a,b>0$

Answer (score 2):

Set
$$
g(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ccc}
x\,f\big(\frac{a}{x}+b\big) & \text{if} & x>0,\\
0 & \text{if} & x=0.
\end{array}\right.
$$
Clearly, $g$ is continuous in $[0,\infty)$, as $\lim_{x\to 0}f\big(\frac{a}{x}+b\big)$ exists.

Next
$$
g'(0)=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{g(x)-g(0)}{x}=\lim_{x\to 0}\,f\Big(\frac{a}{x}+b\Big)=A.
$$
We need to find $A$.

Meanwhile, for $x>0$,
$$
g'(x)=f\Big(\frac{a}{x}+b\Big)-\frac{a}{x}\,f'\Big(\frac{a}{x}+b\Big).
$$
But as the limit
$$
\lim_{x\to 0^+}g'(x)=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\bigg(f\Big(\frac{a}{x}+b\Big)-\frac{a}{x}\,f'\Big(\frac{a}{x}+b\Big)\bigg)=c,
$$
exists, then it has to be equal to $g'(0)$. Thus $A=c$.

We use the following theorem:

*If $f: [a,\infty)\to\mathbb R\,$ is continuous, and differentiable in $(a,\infty)$, and $\lim_{x\to a^+} f(x)$ exists, then $f$ is also differentiable at $a$, and $\,f'(a)=\lim_{x\to a^+}f'(x)$.*

**Note.** We have not used that $\lim_{x\to 0}f\Big({a\over x}+b\Big)\ne 0$.

Comment: How could your work, and the theorem quoted, be affected by the fact that  your $\;g\;$ is defined **only for** $\;x\ge0\;$ and, thus, what you evaluated there is only $\;g'_+(0) = $ the right derivative at zero ?

Comment: The function $g$ plays an auxiliary role. We don't care if it is not defined in the negative half-line. We only use the fact that $g'(0)$ exists!

Comment: Thanks, but the function **must** be defined in a whole (left and right) neighborhood of a point to have a chance to be continuous there, and also to hace a chance to be differentiable there, otherwise we're talking only of one sided derivative. Also, in your last note: you did use the fact the limit exists (finitely) to show continuity of $\;g\;$ at $\;x=0\;$ (from the right)

Comment: Not true! According to what you say $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ can NOT ne continuous at $a$ or $b$!

Comment: You only need to postpone the limits to the very end of the computation using the mean value theorem. $$f\Bigl(\frac ax+b\Bigr)=\frac{g(x)-g(0)}{x}=g'(\xi_x)=f\Bigl(\frac{a}{\xi_x}+b\Bigr)-\frac{a}{\xi_x}f'\Bigl(\frac{a}{\xi_x}+b\Bigr)$$ and now the limit on both sides is equal independent of the value of $g'(0)$.

Comment: @LutzL The formula you provide could shorten my answer, and it is the idea of the proof of the Theorem I am citing.

Comment: @YiorgosS.Smyrlis You may want to calm down. Now, in some books, continuity at the extreme points is understood to be right cont. at $\;a\;$ and left at $\;b\;$, but you surely have seen that differentiability is almost always (for me, always...but perhaps there's some source I may miss) take on open interval. Anyway, your answer is easily fixed and the main idea still works.

Comment: @DonAntonio With all respect, I know what I'm talking about. I've been teaching Calculus and Real Analysis for over twenty years.

Comment: @YiorgosS.Smyrlis I won't continue with this as I think is pointless, with all due respect. To finish this, I'll tell you that I've been teaching Calculus, Analysis, Vectorial Calculus,  Linear Algebra, Differential Equations ,etc. for almost 26 years now. A matter of definition and standards, in my opinion, and a final, absolute matter for yours.

Comment: @YiorgosS.Smyrlis : You need to account in your theorem for examples such as $x^2\sin\frac1x$ which is differentiable but not continuously differentiable in $x=0$. This is a counter-example for your theorem,i.e., the theorem is wrong. It would be true if the assumption were that $\lim_{x\to a+0}f'(x)$ exists.

Comment: Perfect answer +1. Btw I don't see the need for fuss about derivative of $g$ at $0$, be it one sided derivative like you treat or be it the common value from both sides as @DonAntonio points out. Both are fine and applicable equally to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Apply l'Hopital to
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x-b}{\frac{x-b}{f(x)}}\;.
$$
Then you get an expression that is fully in the given limits.

---

$$
…=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{\frac{f(x)-(x-b)f'(x)}{f(x)^2}}=\frac{\Bigl(\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)\Bigr)^2}{c}\;.
$$

Consequently, $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=c$.

Comment: can you continou your answer?

Comment: the question did not tell about the value of $a,b$ spesifically . What will you do?

Comment: In order to apply l'H you need to know that $\;\frac{x-b}{f(x)}\xrightarrow[x\to\infty]{}\infty\;$ , and for this you already need to know, imo, something about the existence and quality of the limit for $\;f(x)\;$ ...

Comment: Per comment, $a>0$ and thus $\frac ax+b\to+\infty$ for $x\to +0$. -- Per assumptions, $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$ exists and is non-zero.

Comment: you already know will use l'H. But this question didn't tell anything about $a,b% spesifically.

Comment: Then use that $\frac ax+b\to+\infty$ for $ax\to0^+$ which only depends on $a\ne 0$.